# Generating access token for getstream feed?

Tags: getstream-io

I am new to getstream - and I am writing some client side code

var streamclient =  stream.connect('xxxxxxxx', null, '11111');

var feed = streamclient.feed('user', 'maurice', **'??????'**) ;

How do I generate the access token for this client ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to keep things secure, you'll first want to get the feed token on the server-side.

When initialising a Stream client on the server-side, you'll pass your app secret which enables access to all your app's feeds. The token can then be passed onward to your client application (single-page app, mobile app etc.).

Example server-side code:

```
var stream = require('getstream');

// pass the app secret when connecting on the server-side
streamclient = stream.connect('<key>', '<secret>', '<app id>');

// no feed token is req'd when the Stream client was connected with an app secret
var feed = streamclient.feed('user', 'maurice');

var feedToken = feed.token // or feed.getReadOnlyToken();
```

The client-side snippet you posted looks fine for initialising the `feed` variable.